# How to select and replace matching syntax in VS Code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am trying to find a quick and easy way to select and replace matching syntax in VS Code. Specifically, I am writing JS / React but theoretically, this could work for several languages.

I have looked for keyboard shortcuts and various extensions to solve this problem and I assume others would benefit from this as well. I am fairly certain this is a solved problem in vim, so I figured there might be a solution for VS Code as well.

Basically, I am looking for a quick way to go from this:

```
const Component = () => (
  <div>some stuff here</div>
)
```

To this:

```
const Component = () => {
  <div>some stuff here</div>
}
```

By simply highlighting and replacing the matching syntax when I do a "special select" of one of the pieces of syntax.

This may seem small, but I do this quite often when I switch from implicit returns to explicit returns within a component. For example, if I am trying to debug and want to add some logic to a component that it did not previously need.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Use an Emmet with react templates in it so you don't have to write the whole boilerplate again and again